# Leer y escribir valor de atributo XML desde Javascript - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Muy buenas tardes, aunque se que pueda ser una consulta basica he intentado algunos metodos y aun no me funciona. Necesito leer un atributo especifico para luego escribirlo con un boton en HTML usando javascript.

Mi codigo es el siguiente :

-- HTML --

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="requestxml.js"></script>

  <h3>Read CSVL</h3>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="readxml()" value="Read xml">

</body>

</html>
```

-- Javascript --

```js
function readxml(){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.clear();
            console.log(this.responseXML);
            var readtagxml = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("tag");

            /*for(i=0; i<readtagxml.length; i++){

                //console.log(readtagxml[i]);
                var dataxml = readtagxml[i].getElementsByTagName("tag");
                console.log(dataxml);

            }*/

            console.log(readtagxml[3]);
            var dataxml = readtagxml[3].getElementsByTagName("value");
            console.log("segundo");
            console.log(dataxml);

        }
    };

    //for test out of plc server use "user/system/dataviews/InkRoom.xml"
    //for test in plc server use "/user/system/dataviews/InkRoom.xml"

    xhttp.open('GET', "user/system/dataviews/InkRoom.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

-- XML --

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/dataview/dataview.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
  <view xmlns="http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/ /schema/dataview.xsd"
    xmlns:cip="http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_types/1.0/" name="InkRoom" description="">
    <tag name="InkR_Full_U" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="read">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Full_OF" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="read">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">FALSE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Full_D" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="read">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Sw_U" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Sw_OF" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">FALSE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Sw_D" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">FALSE</value>
    </tag>

  </view>
```

Lo que necesito es leer y despues escribir el valor de  TRUE o FALSE

```
<tag name="InkR_Sw_U" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
  <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
</tag>
```

Con el codigo actual ya puedo leer el documento xml usando una funcion en javascript y llamandola desde el HTML al accionar un boton. Aun no logro asignarle el valor TRUE o FALSE a una variable definida en javascript y luego con otro boton poder escribir este valor y cargarlo al documento XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de `getElementsByTagName("tag")` deberías utilizar `getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/", "tag")`. Haz lo mismo para las otras llamadas de `getElementsByTagName`, utiliza `getElementsByTagNameNS` y pasale el valor declarado en el documento XML con `xmlns=".."`.

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/dataview/dataview.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
  <view xmlns="http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/ /schema/dataview.xsd"
    xmlns:cip="http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_types/1.0/" name="InkRoom" description="">
    <tag name="InkR_Full_U" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="read">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Full_OF" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="read">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">FALSE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Full_D" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="read">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Sw_U" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">TRUE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Sw_OF" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">FALSE</value>
    </tag>
    <tag name="InkR_Sw_D" valueType="cip:dt_BOOL" path="1,0" display="String" access="write">
      <value xsi:type="cip:dt_BOOL">FALSE</value>
    </tag>

  </view>`;
  
  const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
  
  const tagElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/', 'tag');

  for (let i = 0; i < tagElements.length; i++) {
    let value = tagElements[i].getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/', 'value')[0];
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value.textContent);
  }
```

Comment: He usado getElementsBytagNameNS pero veo que tengo el mismo output, podrias dar un ejemplo de como lo harias, soy un novato aun y no se como pasar el valor con xmlns

Comment: @Brayan, he añadido un ejemplo, espero que te ayude.

Comment: Excelente ayuda ! funciono perfectamente !